# Can Cypress with cucumber replace php unit and regression tests in CI/Cd pipeline?

Tags: cicd, php, regression, unit-testing, cypress

Or there a language agnostic unit and regresion testing?

My team built an MVP with manual tests only and we got into the inverted icecream antipattern. Now to transform into production we need to fix the problem. The marketplace is fully going into Node and JS frameworks and convincing devs to invest more into php is hard considering the job marketplace. Right now we got into a problem that in order to fix 1 bug 2 more appears because there is no regression. Is there a way to fix the icecream antipattern using a php agnostic unit testing? or do we really need to get into phpunit / codeception?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Cypress is capable to run in CI.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Record-tests

Most of the time it is just running `cypress run`. In our case we ran the docker cypress.